# What beasts does Newt Scamander have in his trunk?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-creatures, fantastic-beasts

In the *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* film, Newt Scamander's trunk houses a lot of different magical beasts.  I have recognized the following creatures from the *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* book or the main Harry Potter books.

- Niffler (seeks shiny objects, keeps crawling out of Newt's trunk)
- Demiguise (invisible and generally peaceful, rampaging in the city)
- Erumpent (rhinoceros that blows explosive venom from its horn, has a long chase scene with Newt and Jacob, eventually blowing up a tree with its venom)
- Occamy (hatches from silver eggs, one hatches in the film)
- Clabbert (alarm bird, warned Newt of danger)
- Diricawl (bird that can teleport at will, a pack of chicks seen inside the trunk)
- Mooncalf (Newt asks Jacob to feed them)

But this isn't even nearly the complete list of magical creatures that were shown in the film to have come from the trunk.

**What other magical beasts were there in the trunk?  Could I have recognized any other of them if I read the Harry Potter books and the supplementary books?**  Two I'm missing in particular have important roles in the story: the small creatures that can pick locks and look like green plant parts, and the large four-winged creature that Newt wants to return to Arizona.

(I'm not complaining, I can imagine a lot of reasons why I didn't recognize some creatures.  Maybe I just didn't pay enough attention to the *Fantastic Beasts* book.  Maybe the book was so bad that I succeeded in repressing the memory of most of its contents more than I thought.  Maybe the edition of that book distributed for Muggles is censored, so some creatures are missing from it.  Maybe there are mind-affecting charms cast on the book that make Muggles forget some of the entries, or do not permit Muggles to recognize some of the creatures.)

Comment: This might be a duplicate of http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/63665/9391 "What are all the magical creatures/Beasts in Newt Scamander's suitcase?"

Comment: Cross-site dupes are acceptable where there's no clash of users (e.g. the same person asking on multiple sites )

Comment: Does the billywig count?

Comment: @ibid: Yes, the Billywig counts.

Comment: @ibid - I've added it in. Somehow I missed it on my first pass through the screenplay.

Comment: The **Clabbert** does not show up anywhere in the film or screenplay.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The creature that picks locks is a [**Bowtruckle**](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/bowtruckles), originally described in [Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantastic_Beasts_and_Where_to_Find_Them) as ...

> ...*a tree-guardian creature found mainly in the west of England, southern
>   Germany, and certain Scandinavian forests. It is immensely difficult
>   to spot, being small (maximum eight inches in height) and apparently
>   made of bark and twigs with two small brown eyes.*
>
> *The Bowtruckle, which eats insects, is a peaceable and intensely shy
>   creature but if the tree in which it lives is threatened, it has been
>   known to leap down upon the woodcutter or tree-surgeon attempting to
>   harm its home and gouge at their eyes with its long, sharp fingers. An
>   offering of woodlice will placate the Bowtruckle long enough to let a
>   witch or wizard remove wand-wood from its tree.*

The large four-winged bird is a **[Thunderbird](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Thunderbird)**. This creature (or rather beast) doesn't appear in the original Fantastic Beasts booklet and was, apparently, created specifically for the film.

As was the [**Swooping Evil**](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/swooping-evil)

You've also neglected to mention the [**Murtlap**](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Murtlap) (the beast that bites Jacob), described in Fantastic Beasts as ...

> ...*a ratlike creature found in coastal areas of Britain.
>   It has a growth upon its back resembling a sea anemone. When pickled
>   and eaten, these Murtlap growths promote resistance to curses and
>   jinxes, though an overdose may cause unsightly purple ear hair.
>   Murtlaps eat crustaceans and the feet of anyone foolish enough to step on them.*

And the [**Doxy**](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Doxy), described as being ...

> *often mistaken for a fairy (see page 16) though it is a quite separate species. Like the fairy, it has a minute human form, though
>   in the Doxy’s case this is covered in thick black hair and has an
>   extra pair of arms and legs. The Doxy’s wings are thick, curved, and
>   shiny, much like a beetle’s. Doxies are found throughout northern
>   Europe and America, preferring cold climates. They lay up to five
>   hundred eggs at a time and bury them. The eggs hatch in two to three
>   weeks. Doxies have double rows of sharp, venomous teeth. An antidote
>   should be taken if bitten.*

and the [**Graphorn**](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Graphorn), described as being

> *... found in mountainous European regions. Large and greyish purple
>   with a humped back, the Graphorn has two very long, sharp horns, walks
>   on large, four-thumbed feet, and has an extremely aggressive nature.
>   Mountain trolls can occasionally be seen mounted on Graphorns, though
>   the latter do not seem to take kindly to attempts to tame them and it
>   is more common to see a troll covered in Graphorn scars. Powdered
>   Graphorn horn is used in many potions, though it is immensely
>   expensive owing to the difficulty in collecting it. Graphorn hide is
>   even tougher than a dragon’s and repels most spells.*

and the [**Fwooper**](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Fwooper), ...

> *... an African bird with extremely vivid plumage; Fwoopers may be
>   orange, pink, lime green, or yellow. The Fwooper has long been a
>   provider of fancy quills and also lays brilliantly patterned eggs.
>   Though at first enjoyable, Fwooper song will eventually drive the
>   listener to insanity and the Fwooper is consequently sold with a
>   Silencing Charm upon it, which will need monthly reinforcement.
>   Fwooper owners require licences, as the creatures must be handled
>   responsibly.*

and [**Grindylows**](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Grindylow), ...

> *... A horned, pale-green water demon, the Grindylow is found in lakes
>   throughout Britain and Ireland. It feeds on small fish and is
>   aggressive towards wizards and Muggles alike, though merpeople have
>   been known to domesticate it. The Grindylow has very long fingers,
>   which, though they exert a powerful grip, are easy to break.*

and the [**Nundu**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jO0bSZoPPyg), previously referred to in Fantastic Beasts as a *Nudu*.

> *This East African beast is arguably the most dangerous in the world. A
>   gigantic leopard that moves silently despite its size and whose breath
>   causes disease virulent enough to eliminate entire villages, it has
>   never yet been subdued by fewer than a hundred skilled wizards working
>   together.*

and the [**Billywig**](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Billywig), described as...

> ...an insect native to Australia. It is around half an inch long and a
>   vivid sapphire blue, although its speed is such that it is rarely
>   noticed by Muggles and often not by wizards until they have been
>   stung. The Billywig’s wings are attached to the top of its head and
>   are rotated very fast so that it spins as it flies. At the bottom of
>   the body is a long thin sting. Those who have been stung by a Billywig
>   suffer giddiness followed by levitation. Generations of young
>   Australian witches and wizards have attempted to catch Billywigs and
>   provoke them into stinging in order to enjoy these side effects,
>   though too many stings may cause the victim to hover uncontrollably
>   for days on end, and where there is a severe allergic reaction,
>   permanent floating may ensue. Dried Billywig stings are used in
>   several potions and are believed to be a component in the popular
>   sweet Fizzing Whizbees.

---

The **Niffler, Demiguise, Erumpent, Occamy, Clabbert, Diricawl** and **Mooncalf** all appear in the source booklet along with a brief description of their behaviours, food sources and natural locations.

Notably, the **Clabbert** doesn't appear in the film although it does appear in the [tie-in video game](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Fantastic_Beasts:_Cases_from_the_Wizarding_World). The [**Marmite**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/146452/20774) does make an appearance, but isn't named in the film, script or sourcebook.

Comment: In the film, where did we see the rest of those creatures (Doxy, Graphorn, Grindylows, Nundu)?

Comment: @b_jonas The grindylow was floating around in a bubble of water inside the suitcase when he first takes Jacob in. Was the graphorn the beast with the zoidberg looking mouth?

Comment: @CandiedMango http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/63668/9391 claims to know which one the Graphorn is.;

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to describe their role in the film (through either screenshots or quotes from the script) than to be quoting the 2001 book? The question wasn't asking for more information on those creatures, it was asking which ones appear.

Comment: @ibid - This was largely addressed at the question asked in the body; "*Could I have recognized any other of them **if I read the Harry Potter books and the supplementary books?***". Screenshots are pretty, but also pointless since they're already available at the links.

Comment: The **Clabbert** does *not* show up anywhere in the film or screenplay. Consult [my answer here](http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/63668/42655) for a complete list of creatures in Newt's suitcase that make a film appearance, complete with descriptions, citations and notes about their textbook or screenplay mentions.

Comment: @Valorum 1. This is perhaps not the best place to discuss my answer to a different question, it'd be better discussed in chat, or better yet, in a comment to my answer, rather than here. 2. The question I answered is looking for **magical creatures**, not "Beasts", if that's what concerns you. 3. The Dung Beetle in the film is *not* "just [an] animal", that's actually false, and I even explain it in my answer (which is quite detailed).

Comment: @ghotiandchips - Your answer is very nicely detailed and I applaud the effort that's gone into it. There is, of course, nothing to stop you copying and pasting it over here if you want to do so.

Comment: @Valorum Cheers for the applause :) I saw comments on my answer referring me to your answer here for creatures I missed (Fwooper and Grindylow), so I went ahead and bought the screenplay ebook and decided to make a complete list. No need to copy+paste onto here for aforementioned reason (you helped me). PS: Beast, creature and animal are, according to screenplay, correct terms for all of the creatures inside Newt's suitcase, it's "magical" which denotes their difference from non-fictional animals. The dung beetle is certainly magical (its size), not sure about Glow Bug, my bet's on magical.

Comment: The Swooping Evil link doesn't work.