# What creature is this? (Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them)

Tags: harry-potter, magical-creatures, fantastic-beasts

The following quote is from an [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/63668/42655) for the [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/63665/42655) *'What are all the magical creatures/Beasts in Newt Scamander's suitcase?'* in the Movies & TV SE:

> - Newt is seen bottle-feeding a **luminescent creature** with tentacles
>     [image]
>     *ANGLE ON NEWT, now cradling a **luminescent creature with sprouting alien-like tendrils**. He feeds
>     the creature with a bottle, while carefully watching how Jacob handles the Mooncalves—he recognizes
>     a kindred spirit.*
>     <sup><sub>—*Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them: The Original Screenplay* by J.K. Rowling, SCENE 47, INT. Newt's Case, Animal Area ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D864g.jpg))</sub></sup>
>
>   This creature appears to be unnamed at the time of writing this. The only description we have comes from the screenplay and film. I will edit this post to add the name, whenever it inevitably surfaces.

Can anyone **identify** this animal/creature/beast?

Comment: Maybe a Grindylow?

Comment: @ibid Hi, ibid :) consult the answer I linked at the start of my question, you'll see that the **Grindylow** had already been identified, and you can see it looks much different.

Comment: Then I guess it's not a Grindylow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the VFX house who created the effect, it's a **Marmite**. Note that this creature doesn't appear in any existing Potter property, including the Fantastic Beasts book.

> On the creatures side, **Method handled the shot of Newt bottle-feeding
>   a young marmite – a tentacled cross between a dust mite and squid with
>   a transparent body.** Production provided live action plates with the
>   actor, and Method artists added the CG creature to the shot, digitally
>   wrapping 10-foot long tentacles around Newt and creating an underwater
>   feel.
>
> <sub><sup>[DELUXE’S METHOD STUDIOS CONTRIBUTES VFX MAGIC TO WB’S “FANTASTIC
>   BEASTS AND WHERE TO FIND THEM](http://www.cgsociety.org/news/article/2877/deluxe-s-method-studios-contributes-vfx-magic-to-wb-s-fantastic-beasts-and-where-to-find-them-)</sup></sub>

[image]
[image]

---

This seems to be confirmed by the film's Concept Artist, Dan Baker. On [his website](https://www.danbakerart.com/2016/12/6/shrimp-creature) he has a large range of concept images. The filename for the picture is "***marmite***_V009_DB.jpg" (also referred to as "*shrimp creature*" here and in the [Art of Fantastic Beasts](https://www.harpercollins.co.uk/9780008294410/the-art-of-fantastic-beasts-the-crimes-of-grindelwald/) book).

[image]

> “THE SHRIMP CREATURE The one was a lot of fun. I was asked to look at
>   different types of transparent sea creatures to help capture some of
>   its more grotesque otherworldly qualities. The tentacles were actually
>   inspired by the bodies of hagfish which I thought where creepier
>   somehow than traditional tentacles found on squid or octopuses. DB”

---

A similar level of confirmation comes from the website of [FrameStore](https://www.framestore.com/fantasticbeasts) (the company that provided the film's art design and animations). The filename for the image below is "*bos_20160517_**marmite**_v009c_bk_copy.jpg"*

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! (pun not intended, I generally love using this word, a la David Tennant's Doctor Who) Thanks to you, the list of magical creatures/beasts (referenced in my question) is now the most complete list of correctly identified (and sourced) *Fantastic Beasts* animals. There is only one animal I have left out which I might add, but it's even more minor than the dung beetle, lol.

Comment: They're already had HP films set in Europe and America ... next time round, we'll have one set in Australia and this creature will be called a **Vegemite**.